# Can I avoid lower-case global variables being shadowed in types?

Tags: idris, idris2

The following code compiles okay in Idris2:

```
C : Nat
C = 2

claim : C = 2
claim = Refl
```

but it fails if `C` is not capitalized:

```
c : Nat
c = 2

claim : c = 2
claim = Refl
```

The error message is

> Warning: We are about to implicitly bind the following lowercase names.
> You may be unintentionally shadowing the associated global definitions:
> c is shadowing Main.c
> Error: While processing right hand side of claim. When unifying:
> 2 = 2
> and:
> c = 2
> Mismatch between: 2 and c.

Is there a way to tell Idris compiler not to shadow lowercase global names in types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there's a compiler option or the like, but you can qualify `c`. If it's in module `Foo`, use

```
c : Nat
c = 2

claim : Foo.c = 2
claim = Refl
```